# Producing Spring Boot SOAP Service with SAML protection

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, soap, saml

I need to produce an SOAP Service with Spring Boot. That must be secured by SAML Token.

For now I have the SOAP Service running and tried to implement the authentication thing.
I started with a Wss4jSecurityInterceptor and Username / Password validator. Thank works well. But now I have to change it to validate the SAML Header given bei the SOAP Request (inside SOAP Header).

That is what I use to far for Username / Passwort validation.

```
    @Bean
    public Wss4jSecurityInterceptor requestInterceptor() {

        Wss4jSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor = new Wss4jSecurityInterceptor();
        securityInterceptor.setValidationActions("UsernameToken");
        securityInterceptor.setValidationCallbackHandler(securityCallbackHandler());
        return securityInterceptor;

    }
```

Can anyone help we what to change to validate against the SAML part?